# Divider decoration for constraint layout flow helper children

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, dry

As you may know, you can set a `RecyclerView.ItemDecoration` for RecyclerView's Items. However, I want to achieve something similar to that but for `ConstraintLayout`'s `Flow`.

Currently, I can create multiple divider views and put them inside my flow after each normal view but that can be cumbersome when my `Flow` has multiple views and that's not `DRY` and is an example of repeating yourself. Also, it's worth noting that you cannot reference the same view more than once in `Flow` so you cannot create a divider view and reference it multiple times in different positions. Pragmatically I can create a custom background/style for `TextView` with a line under them to somehow replicate a divider but what if `Flow`s children are not `TextView`?

[image: flow with repeating dividers]

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:checkable="true">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.helper.widget.Flow
            android:id="@+id/product_item_detail_flow"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="8dp"
            app:constraint_referenced_ids="product_item_category,materialDivider,product_item_name,materialDivider2,product_item_price"
            app:flow_verticalGap="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/product_item_image"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <com.google.android.material.divider.MaterialDivider
            android:id="@+id/materialDivider"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <com.google.android.material.divider.MaterialDivider
            android:id="@+id/materialDivider2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/product_item_name"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            tools:text="@tools:sample/lorem" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/product_item_category"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            tools:text="@tools:sample/lorem" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/product_item_price"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            tools:text="@tools:sample/us_zipcodes" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/product_item_image"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/product_image"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/product_item_detail_flow"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".33"
            tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

Consider another flow like this with multiple views that putting a divider after each item is not wise in my opinion:

[image]

So in short how can I create a divider item decoration for constraint layout's flow children?

Edit: both of these flows are actually item for a recyclerview

Comment: Then why not use recyclerview, otherwise I see no way of doing this. Use a custom viewgroup maybe?

Comment: @cmak This itself is an item in a `RecyclerView`, I don't think it's wise to create nested `RecyclerView` only for the sake of dividers.

Comment: I don't understand, why isn't the whole thing in a RecyclerView? Why use Flow?

Comment: @cmak There is a `RecyclerView` and this `Flow` is the item of that. If I replace this `Flow` with another `RecyclerView` then it will be a nested `RecyclerView` which is not performance friendly.

Comment: Sorry, as I can't provide a useful answer, but I'd say if the list is small, then do it manually (even if it's not DRY), if it's long then try to do it programmatically. Either way, I'd use something that just works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find a way to achieve this using `ConstraintLayout` and `Flow`, however, this can be achieved using [`FlexboxLayout`](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout). Because `FlexboxLayout` has a `dividerDrawable` attribute that automatically puts a divider between child views.

After adding the `FlexboxLayout` library to your app/module you can use it like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:alignItems="stretch"
        app:dividerDrawable="@drawable/flex_divider"
        app:flexDirection="column"
        app:showDivider="middle">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="63dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="126dp" />

    </com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

and for `@drawable/flex_divider` create this:

```xml
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <size
        android:width="2dp"
        android:height="2dp" />
    <solid android:color="?colorPrimaryDark" />
</shape>
```

This ultimately results in:
[image: flexbox]